# Is way to open iphone "add to home" screen through javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, web-applications

I am developing web-application using tapestry. In my landing page I have added apple touch icon link.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="${context:layout/images/App_icon.png}"> </link>
```

When user come to my landing page, I want to open "add to home" screen automatically.

Is way to open iphone "add to home" screen through Javascript or jquery?

Please give me your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen plugin. I think it will give you the result needed.